# Vector by Matrix Derivatives in Computational Graphs

Tags: matrix-calculus

I'm trying to learn how to implement the back propagation pass given a computational graph. I've been following the following guide: https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/htang2/mlg2022/tutorial-3.pdf

In equation (4), page 4 of the PDF, the author writes $\frac{\partial L}{\partial A} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial g} \frac{\partial g}{\partial A} = x^T\frac{\partial L}{\partial g}$ where $g(x,A) = xA$ and $x$ is a row vector.

I'm unsure how the author computed $\frac{\partial g}{\partial A} = x^T$ as implied by the above equation. Since the image of $g(x, A)$ is a row vector and $A$ is a matrix, $\frac{\partial g}{\partial A}$ is a row vector by matrix derivative, which I expect to be a tensor?

Where did the $x^T$ come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{trace}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Adhering to a strict naming convention will avoid confusion in these kinds of problems.

Use uppercase/lower Latin letters for matrix/vector variables and Greek letters for scalars.
Furthermore, use column vectors by default and denote row vectors with **explicit** transposes.

For the current problem, rename the variables as follows
$$ L,g,x \quad\to\quad \l,\,g^T,x^T $$

And to eliminate silly transposition errors,
always use the Frobenius product $(:)$ which has the following properties
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
B:B &= \frob{B}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
\LR{XY}:B &= X:\LR{BY^T} \;=\; Y:\LR{X^TB} \\
}$$
Finally, you are correct that $\gradLR{g}{A}$ is a tensor.

The good news is that you **never** need to calculate it.

---

Let's apply the above ideas to your question
$$\eqalign{
g &= A^Tx \qquad &\{ {\rm write\ }g\ {\rm as\ a\ column\ vector} \} \\
\c{dg} &\c{= dA^Tx}
  &\{ {\rm differential\ of\ }g{\rm\ in\ term\ of\ }A^T \} \\
p &= \grad{\l}{g} \qquad &\{ {\rm gradient\ of\ \l\ wrt\ }g \} \\
d\l &= p:dg &\{ {\rm differential\ of\ \l\ in\ term\ of\ }g \} \\
 &= p:\CLR{dA^Tx} &\{ {\rm rearrange\ this}\ldots \} \\
 &= px^T:dA^T &\{ {\rm transpose\ this}\ldots \} \\
 &= xp^T:dA\qquad&\{ {\rm differential\ of\ \l\ in\ term\ of\ }A\} \\
\grad{\l}{A}
 &= xp^T &\{ {\rm gradient\ of\ \l\ wrt\ }A \} \\
}$$
Reverting back to the original (terrible) variable names yields
$$\eqalign{
\grad{L}{A}
 &= x^T\gradLR{L}{g}
\quad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad
}$$

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot!